# How to use import in the web worker

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import, web-worker

Created an instance of the Worker class in which the file is imported, but an error appears on startup in the console "import declarations may only appear at top level of a module"

Code of the worker call file:

```
const worker = new Worker('./js/workers/calculateRequestData.js', {
  type: 'module',
});

worker.postMessage({ data: '1' });

worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  console.log(event.data);
});

worker.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error.message);
});
```

Code of the file calculateRequestData.js

```
import template from '../Template/template.js';

onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log(e.data);
  postMessage(e.data);
};
```

In network files come with the status 304 (if it helps)

Tried to do:

1. `import template from '../Template/template.js' assert { type: 'module' }`
2. `self.template = require('../js/Template/template.js` // Error: require not found (or does not work, something similar)
3. `self.importScripts('../js/Template/template.js')` // The error is the same as in the previous paragraph, only about importScripts.

All of this doesn't work either

Answer (score 3):

The error was in using the "standard" import... from '...'

The worker file turns into one file with a script, where there should be no exports and imports (in the usual form for modules). In order to import a file, or several files, you need to use `importScripts()` in the worker (you can not use the keyword self). `importScripts()` "expands" the imported file in the worker file.

In the vue cli, the worker files and all its imported files should be stored not in the src directory, but in public. This is due to the fact that they are not compiled into a common bundle, but a request is made to a specific file.

Example of the correct code:

File with a worker call:

```
const worker = new Worker('./js/workers/calculateRequestData.js');

worker.postMessage({...});

worker.addEventListener('message', (event) => 
  console.error(event.data); // handle message
  worker.terminate(); // don't forget to delete worker
});

worker.addEventListener('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error.message); // handle error
  worker.terminate(); // don't forget to delete worker
});
```

File calculateRequestData.js

```
self.importScripts('../Template/template.js');

onmessage = function (e) {
  template.calculate(...) // work with imported filse
};
```

I also ran into a problem when the production build did not work due to the incorrect mime-type ('application/octet-stream') of the worker files and the imported script. This is due to the fact that our server by default have files with such a mime-type, while the browser by default calls the "Save as" modal window. This is treated by specifying in the configuration file for mime types by adding the line 'application/octet-stream' The solution was found here - [application/octet-stream mime type issue with codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744376/application-octet-stream-mime-type-issue-with-codeigniter)

Example:

```
'js' => [
    'application/x-javascript',
    'text/plain',
    'application/octet-stream',
],
```